# Calculate an infinite continued fraction as special function

Tags: continued-fractions

It is possible to convert this infinite continued fraction

$\cfrac{1}{-a+\cfrac{b\;f(0)}{a+\cfrac{b\; f(1)}{-a+\cfrac{b\; f(2)}\ddots}}}$

to a special function ? Please, how do it?

where : $(a,b) >0$ and $f(n)=\cfrac{(n+1)^2}{4(n+1)^2-1}$ , $n \in N$, $f(0)=\cfrac{1}{3}$, $f(1)=\cfrac{4}{15}$, $f(2)=\cfrac{9}{35}$, ...

Comment: Maybe you can just take the first $n$ steps of the fraction and set a denominator to $1$ (or the limit of $f$ as $x\to \infty$). Then calculate the limit as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: How do this Please ?

Comment: @Ragnar how to do it?